# How can I put text below the pics?

Tags: css

How can I put text below the pics?

http://codepen.io/ANDRESRENGIFO2015/pen/zvLKJx

```
<div class="img">
<div class="logo">
<img src="http://www.car-logos.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/tesla.png " alt="tesla " title="tesla " width="250" height="250">
</div>  
</div>
  <div class="img">                                                                                              
<div class="elon">
<img src="http://www.medciencia.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/portadaMusk.jpg " alt="musk" title="musk " width="250 " height="250">
</div>
  </div>

  <div class="img">
<div class="car " >
 <img src="http://www.pluginamerica.org/sites/default/files/imagecache/image_full/vehicle-images/tesla%20motors_model%20s_2.jpg " alt="car " title="car " width="250 " height="250">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Insert a break after the image and then add your text. What's the issue?

Comment: Works fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/trsq71k9/. And is there a reason you're shouting?

Answer (score 0):

Since your `.img` elements are floated you are not containing them correctly, putting a element to act as a container with `overflow:hidden` css property or a clearfix hack does the trick.

[Example](http://codepen.io/Ayeetu/pen/LpBWWp)

I'd recommend reading [this](https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/) article about floats and clearing them if you are new to it.